# Move Azure Instance to different cloud Service

Tags: azure

I am looking for advice on accomplishing the following:

Moving an Azure Instance from one Cloud service to another.

I currently have 3 instances setup, but 2 of them are in the same service, sharing the same IP and DNS Name. I need them to all have separate Dedicated IP/DNS names to deploy the appication properly.

I set up the new service with the desired DNS name, but cannot see how to move the instance. I did see that there is an option to import an instance from storage, though i have not figured out how to put an image in storage.

Any advice? I tried seaching but my google-fu is not helping here

Comment: Do you have more context around what you're trying to achieve? This isn't how cloud services are designed to work. All instances of a cloud service (all web role instances, all worker role instances) run behind the same IP address, with traffic being load-balanced between your role instances. Perhaps you can edit your question with more context?

Comment: "Moving an instance" doesn't really make sense in the world of PaaS Cloud Services. Instances are stateless. It should be possible to create and destroy instances arbitrarily (within availability guidelines) without impacting the functioning service in any stateful way.

Comment: @DavidMakogon The context is not a load-balanced scenario, it is 3 separate servers (AD, Web, SQL) that Should be in 3 different services.

Comment: That's a good clarification to put in your original question (via edit). That said, multiple VMs does not necessarily equate to multiple services. That's certainly an option, but not necessary. You haven't explained the "why" in your question, regarding the need for separate services.

Comment: the why? i have a CRM server, AD/ADFS server and a sharepoint server. all unique servers for unique functions that all need dedicated routes from the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing is working create vhd from the instance. Then delete your instance and spin new instance using the vhd in the cloud service you want.

Comment: this can easily go as comment

Comment: but you should put this as comment.

Comment: This I can do, but have as of yet, figured out how to put the VHD into storage.

Comment: I went ahead and imaged the machine and spun up a new one in a new service. thanks for the answers

Answer (score -1):

Your best option is to find the cloud service package (.cspkg) and upload it along with the configuration file (.cscfg) to the new cloud service.

If you can't find these files, go ahead and recreate them the way you did it for your first service.

Take a look at this link (to package, upload from local/storage):
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-create-deploy/

Comment: Not sure I'd call this a "best option"  as it completely breaks the cloud service scaling model.  If there are multiple instances specifically for scalability of a service tier (such as a web site, or background processing), which is a primary advantage of stateless vm's in cloud services, simply pushing the cspkg to multiple cloud services doesn't solve the problem, as you've now removed the load balancer from the mix. Further, you now have to deploy new cloud services every time you want to scale out.

Comment: As far as I understand, this isn't what we're talking about. We're not discussing the scaling model (or any scaling/load balancing capabilities in his solution for that matter) - this indeed is a horrible solution in that aspect.

We are talking about getting his instances running on a different cloud service. As his roles need separate DNS addresses - I assume these are independent tiers that should be scaled individually in their own cloud service. So in terms of what we know - this is the best option.

Comment: Indeed, I am not using these instances as scalable instances of the same environment. The are 3 separate roles that need to be in different services to be scaled individually.